# Аутентификация через google+. 'ClientId' option must be provided. Как работать с Secret Manager в продакшене?

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus

Сделал аутентификацию через google по [этой статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). В режиме разработки работает все отлично. Запустил продакшн и PowerShell при запуске выдает ошибку: System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.

Нашел информацию, что **Secret Manager используется только в целях разработки**. Ключи и значения хранятся в файле конфигурации JSON в каталоге профиля пользователя. 
**А как же тогда использовать его в продакшене, чтобы избежать этой ошибки?**

Answer (score 1):

Суть Secret Manager в том, что он хранит все ключи или пароли не в папке проекта, а в специальной директории у самого пользователя. Тем самым мы получаем исходный код проекта, который совершенно не содержит в себе персональные данные.

Как это работает:

- Мы жмем ПКМ по проекту - Управление секретами пользователя. У нас откроется пустой файл `secrets.json`. Этот файл ваш персональный, он хранится исключительно на вашем компьютере в директории: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>` (где user_secrets_id - это сгенерированный ключ, находящийся в .csproj файле).
- Добавим в этот файл необходимые нам значения, к примеру как написано в документации:

  ```
  {
    "Movies": {
      "ServiceApiKey": "12345",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movie-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
  ```

  p.s. Мы можем это делать и с помощью команд, например: `dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"`.
- Все, теперь мы можем вызвать из `IConfiguration` необходимые нам данные: `Configuration["Movies:ServiceApiKey"];`.

Вот к примеру я вывожу на чистом проекте .net Core 2.1 значение ключа на экран:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(IConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Secret = Configuration["Movies:ServiceApiKey"];
    }
}
```

---

Теперь что касается - *используется только в целях разработки*: Представьте, что вы пишете что-то Open Source, вы заливаете проект на GitHub и вдруг понимаете, что забыли стереть все ключи из проекта. Все мы люди и часто ошибаемся. Вот чтобы такого не было и был придуман "Диспетчер секретов", ведь все ключи хранятся у вас отдельно от проекта. А вот в рабочем проекте, все ваши настройки следует размещать в [файле конфигурации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) проекта (к примеру appsettings.json) `IConfiguration` должен их подтянуть оттуда.

Ссылки на документацию:

- [Диспетчер секретов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=windows)
- [Конфигурация в .NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый комментарий. Но в принципе, все описанное я понял еще из мануала. **Вопрос больше касался аутентификации через google+ в продакшене**. Так как Идентификатор клиента и Секрет клиента находятся во внешнем файле, то почему то именно в продакшене при запуске консоль выдает ошибку The 'ClientId' option must be provided. **Вопрос как запустить приложение в продакшене, чтоб работала аутентификация, если Идентификатор клиента и Секрет клиента находятся во внешнем файле??**